# Access json data from database

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, eloquent

I have a database. One of the columns has the data stored as a json. The field is form_data.

```
{"id":"1248","goals":"tet","bythe_end":"tet","moving_towards":"tet"}
```

Everything else is normal objects.

This is my query

```
$Goal = Assignments::where(function ($query) {
    return $query->whereNull('deleted_at')->orWhere('deleted_at', '');
})
    ->where('assigned_to', $id)
    ->selectRaw('id,value,completed,created_at,submitted_on, form_data, assigned_to as user_id,admin_note,"1-1" as program')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

How do i display this json data.

Comment: My Laravel is rusty, but I think you need to parse the form_data to JSON, as its fetched as a string. `$formData = json_decode($Goal["form_data"], true);` something like that.

Comment: define display. If you want the data as an object, you can just use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: You can access the column from_data by $Goal['form_data'].

Answer (score 0):

If the goal you want to achieve is to get the decode attribute when retrieving a model instance result you can use [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

By adding

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'form_data' => 'array',
];
```

to your Assignments model it should do the job for you.